# No response for ajax PUT, but response on ajax GET and POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, put

Making a same-domain (http://example.host.com -> http://example.host.com) POST, the responseXML contains the expected data. Making the same request, but as a PUT, the responseXML is null for a successful request. I'm using jQuery.ajax, but I tested a manual implementation as well with the same results.

```
var settings = {
    url: '//' + window.location.host + window.location.pathname,
    type: getRequestType(),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(parms),
    error: function(jqxhr, status, error) {
        console.log('error');
    },
    success: function(data, status, jqxhr) {
        console.log('success:', data);
    }
};
$.ajax(settings);
```

I am using a very simple server request handler that returns a simple json-formatted string.

```
@require_http_methods(["PUT"])
def proxy_update(request):
    out = {
        'type': 'update',
        'success': True
    }
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(out), mimetype="application/json")
```

What is the explanation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per jQuery documentation, not all browsers support all verbs. Quite possibly the browser you are using does not support the PUT verb. Try another browser. If the failure is not with the browser then it is also possible that the server may be configured to ignore the PUT verb.

Comment: Turned out to be the latter of the two possible causes.